# Google Maps API Include Geometry Library Spherical Webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, google-maps-api-3, geometry

I am trying to use the geometry library in my webpack project.I have already installed google maps API with the following npm command:
npm i load-google-maps-api
and it is working fine.I am aware that in order to load the Geometry library outside of webpack normaly what you have to do is just include the libraries=geometry
parameter when you first load the API.

For example:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/jskey=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=geometry">
```

I can not find a way to include it in my webpack project though.
I found this line of code:
`const { computeDistanceBetween } = require('spherical-geometry-js')` that might help  and I included it in my project but I still get this error message

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spherical')"

**EDITED ADDED LATER**
The way that I have loaded the google maps api is the following:

```
const loadGoogleMapsApi = require('load-google-maps-api');
var map;
class Map {
    static loadGoogleMapsApi() {
        return loadGoogleMapsApi({
            key: '****'
        });
    }
    static createMap(googleMaps) {
        var mapOptions = {
            center: {
                lat: 40.7484405,
                lng: -73.9944191
            },
            zoom: 12
        };
        $('#map').each(function() {
           map = new google.maps.Map($(this)[0], mapOptions);                  
        });
     }
}
Map.loadGoogleMapsApi().then(function(googleMaps) {
  Map.createMap(googleMaps);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `libraries` key to specify that you want to load [the "geometry" library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/libraries).

```
const loadGoogleMapsApi = require('load-google-maps-api')

loadGoogleMapsApi({
  key: '****',
  libraries: ['geometry'],
}).then(function (googleMaps) {
  // googleMaps is equivalent to google.maps
  new googleMaps.Map(document.querySelector('.map'), {
    center: {
      lat: 40.7484405,
      lng: -73.9944191
    },
    zoom: 12
  });
});
```

You can either use the [LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLng) class or create objects that follow the [LatLngLiteral](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral) interface.

```
const matches = '(38.0374707, 23.6978864)'.matchAll(/([\d.]+)/g) 
const latLng = new googleMaps.LatLng(matches[0][1], matches[1][1]);
```

Comment: First of all thank you for your response. I have edited my question by adding the way that I have loaded the google maps. The code that I am using is working with no problems, what I am trying is to specificly use the Geometry library with no success.
Specificly I am trying to use this command  
var test = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(zip_code_coordinates, markers[i].getPosition());

I just want to use the the library but I am getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'spherical')"

Comment: So unfortunately my problem still remains.

Comment: Thanks for the extra context! I updated the answer - "geometry" is not loaded by default, so you need to add `libraries: ['geometry']` to tell Google to include it.

Comment: This fixed the first problem but now I am getting the error:
"markers[i].getPosition is not a function" for the following line of code:
markers[i].distance = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(zip_code_coordinates, markers[i].getPosition());

Comment: Where is markers defined?

Comment: I believe that this happens because I am reading them from a json as a string so I will have to get them from the json instead. Just a question about that. I managed to get them in a variable called "coord" but they are a string in the form of "(38.0374707, 23.6978864)" and computeDistanceBetween can not work with a string. How can I creare a variable that I can change it's Latitude and Longitude any time all that in a form that the computeDistanceBetween can accept that variable?

Comment: You can convert it to an object with the same properties as LatLngLiteral (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/coordinates#LatLngLiteral)

Here's a sample using a regular expression to parse the string:
  const matches = '(38.0374707, 23.6978864)'.matchAll(/([\d.]+)/g)
  const latLng = { lat: matches[0][1], lng: matches[1][1] }
  console.log(latLng)

Comment: I used the following way to convert it into an acceptable value:
current_marker_coordinates=new google.maps.LatLng(current_latitude,current_longitude);    

current_latitude,current_longitude are strings.
I am doing this inside a loop thought Do you think it is ok to do new new google.maps.LatLng every time in the loop?

Comment: Yeah, it should be fine. I don't expect the class to be expensive to create since it just holds two numbers (latitude and longitude).